Is a pandas MultiIndex a counterpart to a SQL composite index?
I posted this on reddit some days ago, but haven't received any response.
Everything I've read online about the pandas MultiIndex makes it seem like a counterpart to a SQL composite index.  Is this the correct understanding?
Additionally, MultiIndex is often described as hierarchical.  This disrupts the analogy with a composite index.  To me, that means a tree structure, with parent keys and child keys, possibly with a depth greater than 2.  A composite index doesn't fit this picture.  In the case of MultiIndexes, what are the parent/child keys?

I think you almost answered your question. The key difference between a SQL composite index and a MultiIndex in pandas is the hierarchy with lower-level indexes having more priority.
Consider the following example:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

multi_index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['East', 'West'], ['Retail', 'Corporate'], ['Shirts', 'Pants', 'Accessories']],
                                         names=['Region', 'Customer', 'Product'])

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(12, 2), index=multi_index, columns=['Revenue', 'Profit'])
print(df)

Output
                                  Revenue     Profit
Region Customer Product                               
East   Retail   Shirts            0.469112 -0.282863
                Pants            -1.509059 -1.135632
                Accessories      -1.135632 -0.173215
      Corporate Shirts            0.119209 -1.044236
                Pants            -0.861849 -2.104569
                Accessories      -0.721189  0.265599
West  Retail    Shirts           -0.315196  0.854109
                Pants             0.572192 -0.273712
                Accessories       0.228440  0.574273
      Corporate Shirts           -0.284819 -0.671225
                Pants             0.146182  0.056439
                Accessories       0.423380  0.539674

In this example, we have three levels in the MultiIndex:

The parent level is 'Region' with keys 'East' and 'West'.
The second level is 'Customer' with keys 'Retail' and 'Corporate',
nested under each 'Region'.
The child level is 'Product' with keys 'Shirts',
'Pants', and 'Accessories', nested under each combination of
'Region' and 'Customer'.


Thanks for the example! I did think of such an example, but my problem with "hierarchy" is that the ranking of key columns seems arbitrary, e.g., you can repeat East and West on each record to which it applies, and also do the same for Customer. Let's refer the resulting table as the "full" table, in contrast to your "sparse" table above.  If you then sort on Product, Customer, and then Region, the table will look as if Product is the 1st key. The ranking that one ascribes to the key columns don't seem to affect the relational operations that can be done. Am I missing something?

If we sort the "sparse" MultiIndex df to get the "full" version, where every combination of the index levels (Region, Customer, Product) is repeated for each row, we essentially end up with the index levels becoming columns in the resulting df. Although I agree with your other point. These hierarchies are not as strict as they sound by definition. You can apply any transformation(e.g filtering, sorting, aggregation) with respect to your desired key in the MultiIndex

Thanks, Parman. You confirmed my understanding of MultiIndex. Because of my last comment, I will just use normal columns by default, though as I walk through tutorial material for group-by, I suspect that I'll not able to fully avoid MultiIndex.  I note that a dataframe resulting from a group-by operation is stored in Spyder's Variable Explorer as a "normal" (a.k.a.) full dataframe, even though the index is displayed at the console as hierarchical. groupby's as_index option controls whether the result is a sparse or full table, further suggesting that it is cosmetic.

Actually, one use of MultiIndex that toess beyond cosmetic is MultiIndex columns.  MultiIndex row indexing may be implemented under the hood as a composite index, but that can't be done with column indexing in SQL (or dataframes in other 4th generation languages).  There is often only one row of column headings, so MultiIndex column indexing seems to be unique to pandas (though I can't say that with absolute certainty as I don't know that many languages).
